# How do I compile a preload script w/ webpack in Electron?

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron

Electron 1.6.5, Webpack 2.4.1

I'm using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) with a `webview` component. I inject a preload script into the `webview` that does something like this:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const doSomething = require('./utils/do-some-thing.js');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
   doSomeThing()

  // tell scraper to get started
  ipcRenderer.sendToHost('THING IS DONE', [{ url: document.URL }]);
});
```

`webview` needs this script passed as a `file://` path like so:

```
       <webview
        preload={'./some/folder/preload.js''}
        {...props}
      />
```

The problem is that my webpack setup doesn't transpile `preload.js` because it isn't explicitly called via `require()`.  Then, when I build the app, the path `./some/folder/` doesn't exist.

I've tried setting webpack to create a second compiled script like so:

```
entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/index',
    './some/folder/preload.js'
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app/dist'),
    publicPath: '../dist/'
  },
```

But this leads to a `JavaScript heap out of memory` error, which leads me to believe this isn't correct.

Also: wouldn't this approach duplicate `electron` in the `./dist` folder since it's `require()`'d by both `preload.js` and `index.js` ?

Comment: Did you get `preload.js` to be transpiled by babel in the end?

Comment: did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 13):

You could use the electron-main and electron-preload configurations of webpack:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = [
  {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    target: 'electron-main',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'index.bundled.js'
    },
    node: {
        __dirname: false,
    }
  },
  {
    entry: './src/preload.js',
    target: 'electron-preload',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'preload.bundled.js'
    }
  },
]
```

You get two bundles after building, but Electron is not in either of them, so no duplicates.

Notice the `__dirname: false`, which is required since otherwise webpack replaces `__dirname` always replaced by `/` by webpack, leading to an unexpected behaviour in almost all cases (see [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node__dirname) for further information, should be false by default, but wasn't for me).

Comment: I can't get this working. How do you specify the path in the webview preload attr?

Comment: I can confirm that this answer works for WebPack v5.24 with Electron v12.0

Comment: I get the error `An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.`

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar issue where we had several preload scripts instead of one. Our solution was to use the [CopyPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin). So for us, the config looks like this:

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

plugins.push(new CopyPlugin([{ from: "src/container-with-scripts/", to: "preloadScripts/" }]));

module.exports = {
  module: { rules }, // imported from elsewhere
  target: "electron-renderer",
  node: { global: true },
  plugins,
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".css", ".scss"]
  }
};
```

So we just take the folder containing all our scripts and copy them to the autogenerated .webpack folder.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and here's solution that worked for me:
Electron-webpack documentation now contains example how to add [additional entries](https://webpack.electron.build/configuration.html#additional-entry-points-for-main-process).

```
"electronWebpack": {
  "main": {
    "extraEntries": ["@/preload.js"]
  }
}
```

> Note that you can use the @ alias to reference your main.sourceDirectory
> *in this case it's path to your main process script which will be `src/main` by default*

This adds preload script from `src/main/preload.js` into webpack entries.
Then you need to add preload script into window with

```js
new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")),
    }
})
```

That's all. `__dirname` was giving me relative path and electron requires absolute path for preload script so it was failing. `path.resolve` will get you absolute path needed to make it work.

Comment: Useful share but not an answer to the specific question since it relies on Electron-Webpack which is an entire boilerplate and not presumably is something OP could switch to.

Comment: Note: if like me you already created the boilerplate without this preload option, all you have to do is add it to your package.json. See https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/686#issuecomment-669906036

Answer (score -6):

Electron provides an option to load a script before any other execution in your DOM.

You have to provide your pre-load script file path while creating a browser window and file path of the script should be the absolute.

You can find reference [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window)